# share twitter detail throughout the app

Tags: ios, twitter, authentication, share

I am implement twitter share in my IOS app. I ma using MGTwitterEngine. If I implement login and sharing from the same controller it is working but if I separate  out login and share functionality in 2 controllers it is not working.

> SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *_engine;

_engine returning blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting iOS6 or newer, you'll be better use iOS social API:

```
- (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Great fun to learn iOS programming at appcoda.com!"];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

For more info see here: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/

Comment: I do not want to present comment controller. I want to send the post without  presentViewController. Is this possible?

Comment: Using the social framework maybe is possible, but not that easy. You probably will have to go much lower level, so maybe it's easier using MGTwitterEngine and copying some example. The downside of using MGTwitterEngine is that is not integrated with user profile on the device, if I'm not wrong.